# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Employees;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Workers extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    public Workers() {
        initComponents();
        DBConnect();
    }

    public void DBConnect(){
        try{
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Emplyee";
        String db_uname = "ikot";
        String db_pass = "5556sick6";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, db_uname, db_pass);
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Workers";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs.next();
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String fname = rs.getString("First_name");
        String lname = rs.getString("Last_name");
        String job = rs.getString("Job_title");
        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(fname);
        textLastName.setText(lname);
        textJobTitle.setText(job);
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        textID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textFirstName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textLastName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textJobTitle = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btnFirst = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnPrevious = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnNext = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnLast = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Job Title");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(textID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(textFirstName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 142, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(textLastName))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 33, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(textJobTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 254, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(textID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textFirstName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textLastName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(textJobTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addContainerGap(42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        textID.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

        btnFirst.setText("First");

        btnPrevious.setText("Previous");
        btnPrevious.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnPreviousActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnNext.setText("Next");
        btnNext.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnNextActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnLast.setText("Last");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(btnFirst)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnPrevious)
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(btnNext)
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(btnLast)
                .addGap(22, 22, 22))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnFirst)
                    .addComponent(btnPrevious)
                    .addComponent(btnNext)
                    .addComponent(btnLast))
                .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        try{
            if(rs.next()){
                int col = rs.getInt("ID");
                String id_no = Integer.toString(col);
                String f_name = rs.getString("First_name");
                String l_name = rs.getString("Last_name");
                String job_title = rs.getString("Job_title");

                textID.setText(id_no);
                textFirstName.setText(f_name);
                textLastName.setText(l_name);
                textJobTitle.setText(job_title);
            }
            else{
                rs.previous();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "End of file");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
        }
    }                                       

    private void btnPreviousActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Workers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Workers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Workers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Workers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Workers().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnFirst;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLast;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnNext;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPrevious;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textFirstName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textID;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textJobTitle;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textLastName;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Employees.Workers.btnNextActionPerformed(Workers.java:185)
    at Employees.Workers.access$100(Workers.java:16)
    at Employees.Workers$2.actionPerformed(Workers.java:126)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Every time I am running that code it is showing those errors if I press the next button.
I am running this code on NetBeans 8.0.2 in Windows7 32bit machine.
That would be so much helpful if somebody can help me getting through this problem.

Comment: The error message should tell you which line the error occurred on; can you point us to this line?

Comment: Yes sure. The problem was occurred on line 34. I used ResultSet again which created a variable shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `DBConnect` creates a local `ResultSet` with

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Change that to

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

and your field `rs` will be initialized. At the moment you have a [variable shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Comment: Thank you so much Elliot Frisch. You are a life savor. I could not notice that.

Comment: @MahmudAbdurRahmanToki You may want to change your approach a little, you should be calling `close()`  on your `Connection`, `ResultSet` and `Statement`(s) in the same method that you open them. I suggest you read everything into a `List` of a custom `Object` type with your fields.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch, Sorry I can't understand your advice. Should I not call DBConnect() in constructor? If I use connection for each and every function separately then the code will be larger. Do you have any references on that topic? If you have, I will be so much obliged if you guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Your code might be longer. My [blog](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html), go look up database cursors and understand that your DBA may come and have words with you if you leak them.